# Scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans "list has no attribute shape"

Tags: python, scipy

So this is a really weird problem I've been getting. I'm basically trying to create a practice codebook which uses SIFT features of images that are clustered by the kmeans algorithm in Python. However whenever I run the code I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Python\assignment2\SIFT_Dectection.py", line 34, in    <module>
    codebook, dis = cluster.vq.kmeans(codebook_construction(files[:20]),3)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\cluster\vq.py", line 513, in kmeans
    No = obs.shape[0]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

I assume that this is an error within the vq script for the Scipy library. However, I have other friends who are working on this as well and I am using the exact same code as them with the scipy library but I'm still getting this problem. I've also tried to completely uninstall Python reinstalling everything. I'm running the thing on Windows 7 btw. The code I'm using looks something like this:

```
import cv2
import glob
from scipy import cluster

files = glob.glob('101_ObjectCategories/*/*.jpg')

def codebook_construction(im):

    codebook = []

    for image in im:
        img = cv2.imread(image)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        sift = cv2.SIFT()
        kp, desc = sift.detectAndCompute(gray, None)

        if codebook == []:            
            codebook = desc

        else:
            codebook = np.vstack((codebook, desc))

    return codebook

codebook, dis = cluster.vq.kmeans(codebook_construction(files[:20]),3)
```

The glob function there calls for a library of images I've downloaded from Caltech. I've searched high and low for an answer but it seems that no one has been having similar problems. Hopefully I can get some guidance here

Answer (score 2):

The issue looks to be that `kmeans` is expecting an array, and you're feeding it a list. Try changing the last line of your `codebook_construction()` function to:

```
return scipy.array(codebook)
```